# How to require threading macros

Tags: macros, racket

How exactly do I require threading macros in Racket?
Following this guide: https://docs.racket-lang.org/threading/index.html I try `(require threading)` but I get this error:

`standard-module-name-resolver: collection not found
  for module path: threading
  collection: "threading"
  in collection directories:
   /Users/user/Library/Racket/6.9/collects
   /Applications/Racket v6.9/collects
   ... [163 additional linked and package directories] in: threading
  no packages suggestions are available .`

Comment: They are in a separate package, which you have to install in order to use. Run `raco pkg install threading` to install the package.

Comment: Alternatively: Use the Package Manager in DrRacket (see the File menu).

Comment: Alexis, I can see why you might not feel like taking credit for this answer by making it a full-fledged "Answer", but... wouldn't it be more helpful to later visitors to make it one?